# SQL script that inserts a new row using from multiple related rows under the same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a SQL script that is to insert a new record using data from two rows that are under the same BankID.

My table looks like the following:

```
BankID | ActivityId | DisplayDetails | TransactionDate    | TradingId
============================================================================
1              5         Displayer1        2015-02-02 00:00:00.000    1
1              6         DisplayThis1    2016-02-02 00:00:00.000    1
1              5         Displayer2        1999-02-02 00:00:00.000    2
1              6         DisplayThis2    2000-02-02 00:00:00.000    2
```

My fix is to find find each 5,6 combination and insert a new row with ActivityId 66 that gets the DisplayDetails from ActivityId 5 and TransactionDate from ActivityId 6.

My queries looks like the following:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #EightActivity
FROM Bank B
WHERE B.ActivityId = 6

INSERT INTO #Bank (BankID, ActivityId, DisplayDetails, TransactionDate)
SELECT B.BankID, 66, S.DisplayDetails, B.TransactionDate
FROM Bank B
JOIN #EightActivity S
    ON B.BankID = S.BankID
WHERE B.ActivityId = 5
```

However when I run SELECT * FROM Bank I get a 66 row for each 5 and 6 row, when I should only get 1 66 row per 5 and 6 combination.

```
BankID | ActivityId | DisplayDetails | TransactionDate     | TradingId
=============================================================================
   1            5        Displayer1        2015-02-02 00:00:00.000    1
   1            6        DisplayThis1    2016-02-02 00:00:00.000    1
   1            5        Displayer2        1999-02-02 00:00:00.000    2
   1            6        DisplayThis2    2000-02-02 00:00:00.000    2
   1           66        DisplayThis1    2015-02-02 00:00:00.000    NULL
   1           66        DisplayThis2    2015-02-02 00:00:00.000    NULL
   1           66        DisplayThis1    1999-02-02 00:00:00.000    NULL
   1           66        DisplayThis2    1999-02-02 00:00:00.000    NULL
```

I believe I can utilize the TradingId to achieve the desired functionality, but I'm not sure how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me like a simple join will do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO #Bank (BankID, ActivityId, DisplayDetails, TransactionDate, TradingId)
SELECT t0.BankID, 66, t0.DisplayDetails, t1.TransactionDate, t0.TradingId
FROM Bank t0
JOIN Bank t1 
    ON t0.BankID = t1.BankID 
    AND t0.TradingId = t1.TradingId
WHERE t0.ActivityId = 5
AND t1.ActivityId = 6
```

That's assuming that the Activities should be linked by both `BankID` and `TradingId`, of course. Please note I've also inserted the `TradingId` so that you will be able to link the new row with it's source rows. (not sure if you need it, but better safe than sorry, right?)

To handle multiple records with `ActivityId` 6 as per your comment, instead of using a self join, you can use a sub-query:

```
INSERT INTO #Bank (BankID, ActivityId, DisplayDetails, TransactionDate, TradingId)
SELECT  t0.BankID, 
        66, 
        t0.DisplayDetails, 
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 TransactionDate
            Bank t1 
            WHERE t0.BankID = t1.BankID 
            AND t0.TradingId = t1.TradingId
            AND t1.ActivityId = 6    
            ORDER BY TransactionDate
        ), 
        t0.TradingId
FROM Bank t0
WHERE t0.ActivityId = 5
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: Lets say I had a case where we had one ActivityID 5 and multiple ActivityID 6, it will insert 66 for each ActivityId 6 row. Eg. We have 1 Activity 5 with 3 ActivityId 6, we will have 3 new 66 rows, however there should only be 1 new 66 which uses the earliest ActivityId 6 rows TransactionDate. Any ideas how I can modify this query to cater for this new requirement?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to insert data by *condition aggregate function*

```
INSERT INTO #Bank (BankID, ActivityId, DisplayDetails, TransactionDate)
SELECT BankID,66,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityId = 5 THEN DisplayDetails END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityId = 6 THEN TransactionDate END)
FROM Bank 
GROUP BY BankID,TradingId
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/75e49/1)